# How can I convert RealPlayer RM files to MP3s in OS X?

Tags: macos, conversion, mp3, realplayer

How can I convert RealPlayer RM files to MP3 format (and other iPod-compatible formats) in OS X?

I've found a lot of software for Windows but nothing for OS X. I've also given Switch Free edition a try but that doesn't do anything at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26099/is-there-a-way-to-convert-audio-files-in-mac-os-x-or-the-command-line-without-us